# join two tables and select by name instead of id

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following data in mysql:

table zones:

```
+----+------------+
| id | zonename   |
+----+------------+
|  1 | zoneA      |
+----+------------+
```

table objects:

```
+---------+-------+
| zone_id | name  |
+---------+-------+
|      1  | ball  |
+---------+-------+
```

I want to make a select with a join but using the zonename column instead of the id. Is it possible?

This is the expected result:

```
+----------+------+
| zonename | name |
+----------+------+
| zoneA    | ball |
+----------+------+
```

And I want to mention zoneA in the select, so basically select all records on objects where the zone_id matches with the id of ZoneA.

Thanks

Comment: Add a few more rows with sample data, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: If u want a join on `zonename` from 1st table to `name` in 2nd then yes its possible for sure.

Comment: @jarlh added the expected result.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings, names & line numbers & with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com' and read many hits & answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as tabular initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. PS We can make guesses based on your garbled writing but--This isn't clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly".

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible here is the query:

`select zones.*, objects.* from zones inner join objects on zones.zonename = objects.name;`

Comment: this query does not give results

Comment: that is because zonename is not equal to name
the result will be the rows where zonename and name are the same,
Isn't that what you meant when you said `want to make a select with a join but using the zonename column instead of the id`

Answer (score -1):

You can select whatever columns you like from the tables:

```
select z.zonename, o.*
from zones z join
     objects o
     on z.id = o.zone_id
```